# Neo4j Community Version how to start

Tags: neo4j

I installed the community version of Neo4j.

How do I start/stop the server from the user interface for CE version. With the server version  I knew how to use the .bat or powershell files but the CE version is slightly different. And I see no icon in the Windows Start List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the folder C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.0.1\bin there is the Neo4j icon. If you create a shortcut to it and place it for example on your desktop, then you can start the app from there.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an entry it the start menu or on the desktop to start a launcher application. It then resides in the systray.

There is a video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=Foj2tzq84DY

Comment: I find it in the systray. When I exit the app from the systray however, I see no way to restart it as I have no desktop icon and no start menu entry for it...basically no means to start it again...unless I'm missing something here